Cmake does not create configuration files in /usr/local/lib/cmake
My goal:
I am trying to run ORBSlam3 in a vm hosted in my local machine.In order to that I need to install Eigen3 version 3.2.1 because latest version 3.4.4 that comes with packet manager has compatibility issues with the code I am running.
Steps I have taken:
Before installing Eigen3 I have also installed Pangolin using :
cd ~/Dev
git clone https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin.git
cd Pangolin
git checkout 86eb4975fc4fc8b5d92148c2e370045ae9bf9f5d
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
make -j 3
sudo make install


and opencv too using :
cd ~
$ mkdir Dev && cd Dev
$ git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
$ cd opencv
$ git checkout 3.2.0
mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
$ make -j 3
$ sudo make install

As far as I know usr/local/include folder contains source code and in my case it contains 4 folders eigen3 opencv opencv2 pangolin
And my usr/local/lib/cmake folder  only contains Pangolin folder which contains cmake configuration files.
I tried to build eigen3 using following code and could not generate .cmake files in usr/local/lib/cmake:
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
$ make 
$ sudo make install

When I run build.sh in my Orbslam3 folder I get following output:
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/orbslamhost/Dev/ORB_SLAM3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Build type: Release
-- Using flag -std=c++11.
OPENCV VERSION:
3.2.0
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:47 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindEigen3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" (requested
  version 3.2.1) with any of the following names:

    Eigen3Config.cmake
    eigen3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.

My questions are:
1-Why can't I create Eigen3 configuration files while I can create Pangolin files with same command logic?
2- There is no opencv either but somehow it can be detected How is that possible?
I can edit the question to include files like CMakeLists.Since I don't know what is important or not I want to keep the question as simple as I can.I reviewed similar questions but  I may not have been able to understand it because but I have not written any cmake or source code of the project myself I just added include_directories to CmakeFile in my ORBSlam3 project and it is my first time working with cmake.
EDIT:
I have noticed that my Opencv files are located in /usr/local/share/opencv but my Pangolin file is only located in usr/local/lib/cmake
EDIT2:
When I look at CMakeCache at my orbslam folder I found :
 //The directory containing a CMake configuration file for Eigen3.
Eigen3_DIR:PATH=Eigen3_DIR-NOTFOUND

//Directory of Eigen3
G2O_EIGEN3_INCLUDE:PATH=/usr/include/eigen3

//Build g2o with OpenMP support (EXPERIMENTAL)
G2O_USE_OPENMP:BOOL=OFF

//Value Computed by CMake
ORB_SLAM3_BINARY_DIR:STATIC=/home/orbslamhost/Dev/ORB_SLAM3/build

//Dependencies for the target
ORB_SLAM3_LIB_DEPENDS:STATIC=general;opencv_calib3d;general;opencv_core;general;opencv_features2d;general;opencv_flann;general;opencv_highgui;general;opencv_imgcodecs;general;opencv_imgproc;general;openc$

//Value Computed by CMake
ORB_SLAM3_SOURCE_DIR:STATIC=/home/orbslamhost/Dev/ORB_SLAM3

//The directory containing a CMake configuration file for OpenCV.
OpenCV_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/share/OpenCV



I am not still certain why Opencv and Pangolin are located in different folders.

Path to the Eigen3 config file is /usr/share/eigen3/cmake/Eigen3Config.cmake. It is installed with package libeigen3-dev.

Unfortunately I can't use libeigen3-dev since it won't download 3.2.1 The code I am trying to run is not compatible with the latest version of Eigen3.

If you have built and installed Eigen from sources, then you could see which exact files it installs. (You may even re-run sudo make install for view them again.) Among installed files you should be able to find a file Eigen3Config.cmake, and check in which directory it is created.
